# Problema con Scrollbar Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Hola soy nuevo en la librería *tkinter* y python, estaba practicando con los scrollbar pero no logro vincular el scroll con el canvas, el problema que me sale bloqueado el scroll y muy pequeño ¿hay una forma que el scroll aparezca del porte del canvas? ¿hay alguna forma que el scrollbar me aparezca al final del canvas con place? me gustaría saber el por que me aparece bloqueado, estaba siguiendo el ejemplo: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_scrollbar.htm (les dejo el código)

```py
#Version: Python 3.9.2
from tkinter import *

Ventana = Tk()

Contenedor = Frame()
Contenedor.pack(fill="both",expand="True")
Contenedor.config(width=500,height=500)


Frame_Canvas = Frame(Contenedor,bg="red")
Frame_Canvas.place(x=20,y=20)
Frame_Canvas.config(width=300,height=250)

Mycanvas =  Canvas(Frame_Canvas,bg="yellow")
Mycanvas.place(x=0,y=0)

scroll = Scrollbar(Frame_Canvas,orient="vertical")
scroll.place(x=280,y=0)

Mycanvas.configure(yscrollcommand=scroll.set)
Labelx = 0
Labely = 0
for i in range(15):
    MyLabel = Label(Mycanvas,text="hola mundo")
    MyLabel.place(x=Labelx,y=Labely)
    Labely = Labely + 30

scroll.config(command=Mycanvas.yview)

Ventana.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

he estado buscando y me he encontrado, en el stack inglés, con lo siguiente a ver si te sirve:

Your scrollbars need to have the Frame as a parent, not the Canvas:

```
from tkinter import *

root=Tk()

frame=Frame(root,width=300,height=300)
frame.pack(expand=True, fill=BOTH) #.grid(row=0,column=0)

canvas=Canvas(frame,bg='#FFFFFF',width=300,height=300,scrollregion=(0,0,500,500))

hbar=Scrollbar(frame,orient=HORIZONTAL)
hbar.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X)
hbar.config(command=canvas.xview)

vbar=Scrollbar(frame,orient=VERTICAL)
vbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
vbar.config(command=canvas.yview)

canvas.config(width=300,height=300)
canvas.config(xscrollcommand=hbar.set, yscrollcommand=vbar.set)
canvas.pack(side=LEFT,expand=True,fill=BOTH)

root.mainloop()
```

The reason why this works is due to how pack works. By default it will attempt to shrink (or grow) a container to exactly fit its children. Because the scrollbars are children of the canvas in the original example, the canvas shrinks to fit.

If you want the scrollbars to appear inside the canvas, the trick is to use an extra frame. Place the canvas and scrollbars in this inner frame, turn the borders off of the canvas and on for the frame. Set the background of the frame to be the same as the canvas and it will appear that the scrollbars are inside the canvas.

Dale una vuelta a ver si te sirve.

[Stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7727804/tkinter-using-scrollbars-on-a-canvas)

Comment: Por favor, traduce el contenido en inglés de tu respuesta.

Comment: El scrollbar no se mueve junto con el canvas